# AsyncTask downloaded files with 0B

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I trying to download files with AsyncTask, and all files which are downloaded has 0b. I don't know how to do. Can somebody help? Please help me, I spend all day for this. Where is my mistake? I have never work with AsyncTask, I wrote this code with example.

some code:

```
public class DownloadProgramTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
    int id;
    MYDBHelperFromApi mydbHelperFromApi;
    Program program;
    List<Asana> asanaList;

    public DownloadProgramTask(int id, MYDBHelperFromApi mydbHelperFromApi){

       this.id = id;
       this.mydbHelperFromApi = mydbHelperFromApi;

    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void...params) {

       program = mydbHelperFromApi.getProgramForStart(id);
       asanaList = program.getAsanasList();

        final String FILE_PATH_PROGRAM_VOICE = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Programs/Voice/"+id+"/";

        List<String> voiceList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<File> fileList = new ArrayList<>();
        File dirVoice = new File(FILE_PATH_PROGRAM_VOICE);
        fileList.add(dirVoice);
        for (File f:fileList) {
            if (!f.exists())
                f.mkdirs();
        }
        for (Asana a:asanaList) {

            File voiceFile = new File(dirVoice, a.getPose_id() + ".mp3");

            if (!voiceFile.exists()) {
                voiceList.add(a.getVoice());
                download(MYurl.BASE_URL + a.getVoice(), voiceFile.getPath());
                Log.e("LINK",MYurl.BASE_URL + a.getVoice());
                Log.e("Path voice", "" + voiceFile.getPath());

            }
        }

         return null;
    }
    public void download(String s, String Path_file) {
        InputStream input = null;
        OutputStream output = null;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(s);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
               Log.d("Something went wrong"," "+s);
            }


            int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();


            input = connection.getInputStream();
            output = new FileOutputStream(Path_file);

            byte data[] = new byte[4096];
            long total = 0;
            int count;
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {

                if (isCancelled()) {
                    input.close();
                }
                total += count;

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Exception", e.toString());
        } finally {
            try {
                if (output != null)
                    output.close();
                if (input != null)
                    input.close();
            } catch (IOException ignored) {
            }

            if (connection != null)
                connection.disconnect();
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Is `Log.e("Exception", e.toString());` printing any exceptions for you? I ask because you are creating a file before you are downloading, which would explain why you have a 0 byte file, if the downloading is causing some exception.

Answer (score 1):

Where are you writing the in output stream?

Add this line in while loop in download method:

`outputStream.write(data, 0, count);`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried do a flush before closing the `FileOutputStream`?

try to put `output.flush();` before `output.close();`

```
try {
  if (output != null) {
    output.flush();
    output.close();
  } 
  if (input != null)
    input.close();
} catch (IOException ignored) {
}
```